# Simple past with the "by some point in the past" phrase. What to choose and when?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

Why does it use the past simple tense rather than the past perfect (had been)?

> (1) Odenkirk confirmed by early September 2021 that he was back on set
> filming.

The source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul_(season_6)

Whereas the following use the past perfect:

(2) "*They HAD packed the goods by yesterday.*"

(3) "*The good HAD been packed by yesterday.*"

(4) "*He HAD finished writing his timesheet by 6 A.M.*"

The way I see it, (5) "*The goods were packed by yesterday*" is as equally correct as (3) with a different emphasis. The (5) emphasizes the state of the goods whereas the (3) emphasizes both the state of the goods (packed) and the action performed by someone (packing).

Here are a couple of examples from the web:

> Bayona completed filming on his episodes by December 23.
>
> Pre-production on further episodes began by July 2020.

Why then don't these use the past perfect tense?

Comment: You don't have **have to** use it. But when used, **it precedes another action, either explicit or implied**.  He had come in the door when the phone rang. See? He entered BEFORE the phone rang. That is the main point about the past perfect and there are tons of answers on this site that show this in great detail.

Comment: (So, to address the original "Odenkirk" example: It's not past perfect because presumably his quote was something like "I'm back on set filming." In the past-simple sentence about his September press conference, the only time being discussed is September.

Comment: @Lambie Of course I tried to read all related answers before posting. Your "when" and "before" examples are very well understood, thank you. By I'm struggling with the "by" phrase. What I'm deducing from your post now is that there has to be some **following implied action** to justify using the past perfect. For example, "In early October she learned that Odenkirk had confirmed by early September 2021 that he was back on set filming." I wonder why you say that I don't **have to** use it, though.

Comment: Because you don't. It can be more precise or elegant but sometimes people don't want that level of precision. Imagine an argument: Your boss says: Why didn't you confirm you were not attending? I did confirm it. I confirmed it by August. I really had confirmed it by July 31,

Comment: @Lambie You see... I've never seen such usage backed in any Grammar textbook, namely a past simple action verb followed by "by" and some past point in time... Although I have seen it on Wikipedia.  This is where I got those examples. (And make no mistake - I'm precisely talking about action verbs, not stative verbs).  So it makes me wonder, why this usage isn't covered in, say, Michael Swan's "Practical English Usage" or the like. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong books, huh?

Comment: It's not covered because there is nothing unusual about it. I had made or I made my reservation **by** August 18 when I was asked to cancel it. The by doesn't change anything at all. *by** is not a verb tense trigger.

Comment: @Lambie these two sentences seem to mean different things. "I made my reservation by August 18 when I was asked to cancel it" means "First I was asked to cancel my reservation by the person who mistakenly thought I had already reserved a ticket, then I didn't care about their request, disobeyed it, and made the reservation anyway". "I had made my reservation by August 18 when I was asked to cancel it" means "I made my reservation not later than August 18 and then I was asked to cancel it"

Comment: It's like: "Mom made dinner when we arrived" and "Mom had made dinner when we arrived"

Comment: In the context of reporting or stating a series of chronological facts in an article, you're not as likely to see the past perfect. E.g. the following is unlikely: "Odenkirk had confirmed by early September that he was back on set filming." The Wikipedia article provides a straightforward, chronological narrative, and there is no pre-stated reference point after early September. On the other hand, if the article read: "Odenkirk stated in late September that he [had] finished shooting by early September," I would call the "had" optional and probably desirable due to the later reference point.